# How to generate seasonal time series data in positive value using sim.ssarima in R?

Tags: r, simulation, arima, generate

I want to make X-13 ARIMA-SEATS simulation using seasonal time series data that generate from package `'sim.ssarima'`. But in X-13 ARIMA-SEATS require the data must be non-zero and positive value. Whereas `'sim.ssarima'` generate random value (positive or negative). How to make it become positive value in R?

Here is my code to generate data:

```
ARIMA11 <- sim.ssarima(orders = list(ar=c(1,1), i=c(0,0), ma=c(1,1)), lags=c(1,12), frequency=12, obs=120, AR=c(-0.6, -1), MA=c(0.2, 0.1))

data11 <- ARIMA11$data
```

Comment: Add a constant?

Comment: @BillO'Brien it's great simple idea. thanks